# Moving/Updating slaves configuration to new jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, slave

I have lot of slaves added (nearly 500) to on jenkins server (1.573) in production. I am trying to setup new jenkins server as sandbox. I need the to move some slave machines from production to sandbox environment. I tried to coipy the slaves tag from prod jenkins config.xml and copy to new sandbox jenkins server (same version as prod) and then consolidate the details. But whenever i copy the dsetails and give "Reload from server", the newly added slave details are all reset and it gives me empty list in the nodes.
could any one explain oir give a way to accomplish the above described task ?

Comment: Did you try to copy all the plugins from your old to your new Jenkins server?

Comment: Yes everything is copied !

Comment: If you are on Linux, did you update the SSH keys on the new Jenkins server?

Comment: Yes we have a fully functional production server, all we needed is to split nodes among them